# Multi Sampling in Rendering Pipeline?

Tags: shaders, graphics, rendering, gpu

I am trying to understand : *How does multi-sampling rasterization effects pixel shader output?*

In a nutshell (i am skipping some steps to stay on point of question):

1. Vertex data is fetched.
2. Vertex shader is executed.
3. Rasterizer - rasterizes the geometric region, this is where it is decided which pixels are covered by the mesh/geometry.
4. Pixel shader is executed.

*Multi-sampling Anti aliasing rasterization* which is a rasterization rule, helps to decide weather full color output by pixel shader will be drawn on screen or it will be blended based on multi-sampling result (not by Blending-operation as I am aware that Blending(srcAlpha oneMinusSrcAlpha) happens later in the pipeline before pixel is drawn on screen).

Example MFAA : which uses sampling 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T2UMqmne4RA

My question is where does this sampling information get stored for every pixel and at which step of rendering pipeline, color given by pixel shader is changed based on sampling result done by rasterizer?

Thanks